# Basic information about UK supermarket products

Tags: data-request, food

I am developing an application where a user will scan a barcode of a UK supermarket product. The application will then need to look up:

- The manufacturer of the item
- The product name
- The package quantity

The only absolutely required of these is the product name, but the others would be helpful.

I have tried the Open Product Data and various other similar services, but none of them have records of the supermarket own-label products, only branded ones. I need to be able to look up supermarket own-branded products as well.